# The upside down product sign

Tags: general-topology

I recently encountered the upside down product sign in an exercise. According to Wikipedia, this stands for coproduct. However, I am not sure what it means. As a specific example, here's the exercise:

http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4500/h15/beskjeder/mandatory2015.pdf

It comes after 1a. I am not sure I am interpreting it correctly. Does this mean that whenever I get a set on the lower hemisphere, I have to use $f_L$ and $f_U$ when I have a set from the upper hemisphere? Usually, when I have encountered these kinds of situations, the notation has been the same as is used in defining functions piecewise.This, however, is completely new.

Comment: It says "disjoint union". It just means you've got two copies of $D^n$ that you think of as totally separate; two identical disks floating in some ambient space.

Comment: The symbol $\coprod$ just means disjoint union, which you can define as $A \coprod B = \{ ( 1, a ) \mid a \in A \} \cup \{ ( 2,b) \mid b \in B \} $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coproducts of topological spaces are disjoint unions (as hinted at in your exercise), given the "obvious" topology. More precisely $X \sqcup Y$ can be taken to be $(X \times \{0\}) \cup (Y \times \{1\})$ topologised as a subspace of $(X \cup Y) \times \{0, 1\}$, where $\{0, 1\}$ is given the discrete topology and the product is given the product topology (so the open sets in $X \sqcup Y$ are disjoint unions of open subsets of $X$ and open subsets of $Y$).